# What is the logic of auto generated comments behind Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I try to understand the logic of auto generated comments behind Bitbucket. I explain...

When you go to a branch then you click "Merge" button the commit message generated is something like:

> Merged Hotfix/My-Hotfix-Name into staging

When you go to a branch then you click "Create pull request" the system create a title for your pull request but don't generate a commit message yet. When, from this pull request, you click "Merge" button the commit message generated is something like:

> Merged in Hotfix/My-Hotfix-Name (pull
>   request #113)

Why in first case the system generate a commit message with **into** and then from the second case the message use **in**. I don't get the logic. When I'm merging from a pull request I'm also merging a branch **into** something. I have a problem with this word Merged **in**. What is the grade? For me this **in** should be a **from** or there is something I don't understand.

Comment: I ask this question because I would like to know if this is not important or if I'm really missing or misunderstanding something. For me the correct message is the first one. We merge something from a branch into another branch. The message generated during the merge of a pull request is just not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, it is just semantics. Nothing to lose sleep over.